# How to execute 32 bit programs in Kali Linux 2.7 (64 bit)

Tags: debian, kali-linux, 64bit, x86

I am trying to execute a 32 bit file in Kali. But is says no such file or directory. I tried the following solutions:
[image]

Then, I checked the installed architectures, and i386 is installed it seems.
[image]

I updated the cache using ldconfig. Still I am not able to execute that file.
I am sure that the file exists in that location. And I am able to execute the file successfully in my 32 bit opensuse system. The file is not written by me, so I am unable to provide more details about the file. But I think there is nothing wrong with the file because my friends were able to run it on Ubuntu systems.

Comment: @JuliePelletier - Last part of the image shows the exact response. myls is the file I am trying to run.

Answer (score 3):

You need to install `libselinux1:i386`:

```
apt-get install libselinux1:i386
```